# How to apply the custom theme to EditText in app theme?

Tags: android, xml, themes

I need to set the colorAccent of all EditText controls in my app in the app theme. I tried the following code.

```
<style name="Theme.TestAndroid" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="editTextStyle">@style/CustomEditTextTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomEditTextStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/CustomEditTextTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomEditTextTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

But it doest not work. Why doesn't this code work? How can this be done?